# How to catch spring boot AccessDeniedException when using @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I am trying to catch AccessDeniedException, so I can display the AccessDenied error message in response, instead of `Internal Server Error(s) while executing query`

But, when I try to debug the method, `try/catch` block doesn't catch the `AccessDeniedException` thrown by `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);`
I tried to use recommended @ExceptionHandler , but they did not help either.

Current response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Internal Server Error(s) while executing query"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access denied."
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) {
        Optional<HttpServletRequest> optReq = Optional.of(request);
        String authToken = optReq
                .map(req -> req.getHeader("Authorization"))
                .filter(token -> !token.isEmpty())
                .map(token -> token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
                .orElse(null);

        if (authToken != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            //process token
        } else {
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (AccessDeniedException | ServletException | IOException e) {
                String test = "test";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the mutation where @Preauthorized is used :

```
@Component
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('CREATOR','INFLUENCER','INFLUENCER_TEAMMATE')")
public class ProducerSharedMutations implements GraphQLMutationResolver {
       private final WidgetService widgetService;
       
       public ProducerSharedMutations(WidgetService widgetService) {
       this.widgetService = widgetService;
      }

      public Widget addWidget(WidgetInput widgetInput){
         return widgetService.add(widgetInput);
      }
}
```

Comment: please do not post images of logs, posting images of text is forbidden on stack overflow please read the rules. Also writing a custom JWTFilter is bad practice, and outdated from all blogs that have no idea what they are talking about. You should use the built in jwt filter that comes with spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Comment: @Toerktumlare done. Thank you. I didn't know. Unfortunately the documentation is pretty abstract and all my projects is already configured with current implementation. Thanks anyway for informing. 
Don't you know accidently how this error can be catched ?

Comment: If you feel the docs are abstract read the architecture chapter which explains the fundamentals. And you can always look at the examples provided by spring security. Good luck with your problem, since this is bad practice i will not provide more information than pointing you to how it should be implemented, since this is potentially insecure.

Comment: i am allowed to comment on whatever i want however i want as long as the comment follows the rules. And i am sharing knowledge, that when others see this question, they will know that doing things this way is bad practice, writing custom security solutions are bad practice. Stack Overflow is huge site and many visit and read. Dont take it personally, see this as a learning experience and learn something from it.